# Redirected URL Submit to new window?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible to make a redirect URL submit click open in a new window?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

No, the submit button can't be set up to open a new window. You can have the window that the Cognito Form is currently in redirected, but you can't have a new window opened.